# Pfsense NAT with site-to-site VPN

Tags: routing, vpn, nat, pfsense, port-forwarding

For a client I am building a network solution that enables them expanding their available online presence.

I am running into a problem with port forwarding to an IP which is routed over an OpenVPN L3 site-to-site VPN.

On site A I have public IP 1.1.1.1 which is running the openVPN server. 10.255.0.1/24 is the openVPN tunnel IP.

On site B I have public IP 2.2.2.2 which is running as openvpn Client. 10.255.0.2/24 is the openVPN tunnel IP. Site B is running an apache server on port 80 with IP address 10.30.1.11/24.

RfC1918 is routed to 10.255.0.2, making all possible IPs reachable from site A, proven by ping and reaching port 80 on a server within one of the server vlans at site B from the pfsense console (telnet).

On site A I configured a port forward with destination 1.1.1.1:80, forwarding it to 10.30.1.11:80. Here starts the confusion. I try to reach 1.1.1.1:80 from an external IP (so no weird NAT reflection or so), the connection fails. When I do a tcpdump on said server, I see the packets coming in and getting responded to, but the response packets never reach the firewall on site A. When I set a static route on site B with the IP address of the external source to site A, the connection works.

pfTop on site A&B shows this.

```
  pfTop: Up State 1-2/2 (22), View: default, Order: bytes
PR        DIR SRC                           DEST                                   STATE                AGE       EXP     PKTS    BYTES
tcp       In  3.3.3.3:12226                 10.30.1.11:80                  CLOSED:SYN_SENT     00:00:03  00:00:30        3      180
tcp       Out 3.3.3.3:12226                 10.30.1.11:80                SYN_SENT:CLOSED       00:00:03  00:00:30        3      180
```

I tried setting 10.255.0.1 as a gateway for 10.30.1.11 on site B and a outbound mapping on site A to the WAN, but this did not help.

It feels like asymmetric routing, but as it is session based routing it *should* work.

Comment: You really shouldn't be running an OpenVPN client on site B but a server for site-to-site.

Comment: I made site B the openvpn client as I would be unable to configure a gateway on the interface when it's a server.

Comment: NAT is not a substitute for routing. NAT should only be used for private<->public or overlapping addressing, but it should only be a temporary solution for overlapping addressing while one or both sides are readdressed to fix the conflict.

Comment: @RonMaupin it is private<->public, as 1.1.1.1 is mapped to 10.30.1.11

Comment: The tunnel should be private<->private inside the tunnel. The routers running the tunnel have the public address, so you do not need NAT for the outer tunnel. Also, you do not own `1.1.1.1`, so you should not be using that.

Comment: The tunnel is routed, no nat running over the tunnel. what I am looking for is a port-forward to reach an webserver on the public IP of site A which is actually running on site B. The IPs shown above are not the actual IPs in use, I masqueraded them with example IPs.

Comment: I don't know about the 'session based routing' on PFsense specifically but I can basically comment that you are doing this 'wrong'. You should ideally just do the NAT at site B because the server is at site B. Doing otherwise is creating problems that don't need to be there. Aside from that, you do have a routing issue because the client for the web site is just on the internet and the default route on the server at site B says that the internet is reached via the site B firewall and the site B firewall sends the return traffic out to the internet, not over the tunnel.

Comment: For example, say website client is IP 5.5.5.5 and wants to hit the site, they connect over the NAT and eventually over the VPN to the server at site B. Site B server sends the reply traffic out its internet service because the firewall at site B says 5.5.5.5 is out its default route, not over the VPN. Because there is no NAT table entry for that reply traffic, it is dropped on the firewall or if it goes out, it is dropped at the client because the source (site B firewall) is not the IP it connected to (site A firewall). So just put the NAT on Site B firewall and all is well.